# nan error in load Advertising box inside the li element

Tags: html, jquery, html-lists, ads, nan

i write this code, it's right but show nan error after Advertising img.

Does anyone know where this error comes from and how can I fix it?

my code in html:

```
<div>
 <ul class="list-groupJournalList">
 </ul>
</div>
```

my code in jquery:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
  

        inner1 = ('<li class= "list-group-item">' +

            '<div class="col-xs-12 article-wrapper">' + '</div>' +

            '</li>');

       
        advboxx = ('<li><div class="advertising-SearchReasultBox">' +
            '<img src="../FrontEnd/media/image/Sid-adv1-moavenatelmi.gif" height="80"/>' +
            +'</div></li>');

        for (k = 1; k < 3; k++) {
        $('.list-groupJournalList').append(inner1);
        }
        $('.list-groupJournalList').append(advboxx);

    }
```

The output is similar to the image below:
[nan error in image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F3l4Y.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you forgot to close your function, the "for" loop and there's an extra "+" here *at the beginning of the 3rd line* :

```
advboxx = ('<li><div class="advertising-SearchReasultBox">' +
            '<img src="../FrontEnd/media/image/Sid-adv1-moavenatelmi.gif" height="80"/>' +
            +'</div></li>');
```

Try this :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
     for (var i = 1; i <= 100; i++) {
         inner1 = '<li class= "list-group-item"> <div class="col-xs-12 article-wrapper"> </div> </li>';
         advboxx = '<li><div class="advertising-SearchReasultBox"> <img src="../FrontEnd/media/image/Sid-adv1-moavenatelmi.gif" height="80"/> </div> </li>';

         for (k = 1; k < 3; k++) {
            $('.list-groupJournalList').append(inner1);
         }
         $('.list-groupJournalList').append(advboxx);
     }
});
```

Comment: because there's an extra "+" in: **advboxx** in front of "*'</div></li>');*" that's why it's retuning NaN.